# Iterating Objects in Node.JS for HTTP response

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an object array in Node.JS and I wish to response.write(); it to the screen, I can manage to get the first object out but the loop stops and only the first is outputted, can anybody point me in the right direction...

```
db.collection('todo', function(err, collection){            
                    collection.find(function(err, cursor) {
                        cursor.each(function(err, doc) {
                            for(docs in doc){
                                if(docs == "_id"){

                                }else{
                                    var test = docs + " : " + doc[docs];


                                }

                            }
                            data = data.toString("utf8").replace("{{TEST}}", test);
                            response.write(data);
                            response.end(); 
                        })                    
                    });
                });
```

Comment: Soon as you call response.end, that finishes the response.  Do you mean to call response.write instead?

Answer (score 2):

Move `response.end()` out of the loop. That should do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `response.end(data);` to `response.write(data);`

Note that this will asynchronously append to the stream going to the user.

If you plan to dump them all at once you can also try:

```
cursor.toArray(function (err, docs) { 
  /** run a for loop over each doc in docs **/
})
```

Comment: I've changed response.end(data); to response.write(data); response.end(); although the same issue still persists, I tried moving response.end() to the end of the db.open also but this resulted in nothing being responded at all

Comment: you need the response.end after the last adync callback; at the end of db.open likely fires before any writes.

Comment: Placed it there but still no iteration, see code in original post (updated it)

Comment: Your `response.end()` cannot be there. Read the code, it says: *"foreach document on this cursor, write the document to the response stream and then end the response stream"*... you are effectively ending the response for each object coming back from MongoDB. Clearly this is not what you want to do.